# EntityFramework upgrade & errors in Designer.cs file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I upgraded the EntityFramework in my MVC project (from 4 to 6).

I got lot of errors in Designer.cs. All errors are

`"wrong path to library" type`.

So I tried to change `System.Data.Metadata` to `System.Data.Entity.Core` and so on.

After changing path I got no errors, but I know that I should not to change that file directly but through the edmx file because if change the edmx file my Designer.cs consist the wrong paths again.

What is the solution of EntityFramework change and its impact on Designer.cs? How to replace abandoned paths on a correct way?

Comment: The upgrade path from EF4 to 6 is [well documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469466%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I didn't see any .tt files so I added EF 6.x DbContext Generator  and got .tt files. In edmx file I changed Code Generation from T4 to LegacyObjectContext and again got hundreds of errors. Now, I don't understan the 4th step. I can update System.Data to System.Data.Entitiy.Core but not in Design.cs because it is autogenerated and it is still old namespaces after adding EF 6.x DbContext Generator

Comment: If I leave T4 code generation my  Designer.cs file is empty and I have 20 errors because of lack of AddObject definition.